# Images shown rotated in Codename One

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm developing a Codename One app for iOS.

I gave the user the option to take pictures or to load them from the gallery of the device. After that, the app shows pictures in labels (encapsulated in a BoxLayout). 
When I take pictures in portrait mode, everything perfectly works, but when I take pictures in landscape mode, that picture is shown rotated (a 90° rotation).

Here is the code:

```
String filePath = Capture.capturePhoto();
if (filePath != null) {
    try { 
        Image img = Image.createImage(filePath);
        if (img != null){
            setImageToContainer(img);
        }  
    } 
    catch (IOException err) {
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Problemi con le immagini: " + err.getMessage());
        completeImageName = null;
        fileImageName = null;
    }   
}

private void setImageToContainer(Image img){
    Label imgLbl = new Label();
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Button");
    FontImage p = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_PORTRAIT, s);
    EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(p.scaled(p.getWidth() * 3, p.getHeight() * 4), false);
    imgLbl.setIcon(placeholder);
    list.add(imgLbl);
    //Scalo l'immagine
    if(img.getWidth() > imgLbl.getParent().getWidth()) 
        img = img.scaledWidth(imgLbl.getParent().getWidth());
    if(img.getHeight()> imgLbl.getParent().getHeight()) 
        img = img.scaledHeight(imgLbl.getParent().getHeight());
    imgLbl.setIcon(img);
    list.repaint();
}
```

Reading [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51490256/4948006), I understood *Image.createImage(filePathToImage)* method takes in account EXIF data, in order to properly rotate the image.

How can I solve my problem? Is there a way to get EXIF data?

Comment: This should be seamless in Codename One as indicated here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/423 It's possible that this is a regression so I suggest filing an issue

Comment: Done: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2790